# My app doesn't appear in list of apps to complete set alarm action using Google Assistant on Android 13

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, android-13

I have been trying to add support to my app to allow users to set an alarm using Google Assistant voice actions. I have followed these two set on instructions:

https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#dynamic

I am having some trouble on Android 13. When I give a voice command using Google Assistant to set an alarm, I don't see my app in the list of apps that can be used to complete the action. However, there is a keyboard that appears in the Google Assistant interface which can be used to type the command that you want to run. For e.g., I can type "Set an alarm for 2 pm to water plants" and it will set the appropriate alarm. For commands entered via the keyboard, my app appears fine.

On Android 12 and below, the app appears find during voice commands also. So, there seems to be some extra step that I need to run for my app to appear during set alarm voice action. I installed some other alarm apps and they appear fine in the list of apps to complete the voice action.